# Howto set a host virtual interface (failover) to a vm in kvm+libvirt?

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, ubuntu-20.04

Have a Ubuntu Server 20.04 and 2 address, one in `eno1` interface with first default public address and a failover with second address.

I can create a virtual interface using a netplan called `failover1` and works fine:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
            set-name: eno1
    bridges:
        failover1:
            addresses:
                - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32
            dhcp4: true
```

```sh
root@server:~# ip addr
...
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 86125sec preferred_lft 86125sec
...
4: failover1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 scope global failover1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My virtual machine works fine using the default nat network:

```xml
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>...</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

When navigate using a web browser use the primary public address, but need use the **secondary address only**.

I try creating a phisical brigde using:

```xml
<network>
    <name>bridged-network</name>
    <forward mode="bridge" />
    <bridge name="failover1" />
</network>
```

But virtual machine has not internet access, but from host using wget works fine:

```sh
wget -qO- http://checkip.dyndns.com/ --bind-address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</body></html>
```

I try using a passthrout but does not work:

```xml
 <network>
   <name>passthrough</name>
   <forward mode='hostdev' managed='yes'>
     <pf dev='failover1'/>
   </forward>
 </network>
```

```sh
root@server:~# virsh net-start passthrough
error: Failed to start network passthrough
error: internal error: No usable Vf's present on SRIOV PF failover1
```

I try using direct network device in mode `vepa` and `brigde`:

```xml
<interface type='direct'>
  <source dev='failover1' mode='vepa'/>
</interface>
```

But does not have internet connection from vm.

How to set the specific failover address or interface to the virtual machine?